# How I can fix it this "replaceAll" error?

Tags: java, replaceall

[image]

How I can fix it?

```
String replace1 = WEBSITE.replaceAll("{fromNumber}", number);
```

this character "{" error in replaceAll function. Thank you

Comment: Read the javadocs for `replaceAll`.  The first argument is a regex, not a simple string.  Now read the javadocs for `Pattern` to find out the **syntax** for regexes in Java.  Hint: `{` is a regex meta-character, and it needs to be escaped with a `\`.  But a `\` in a string literal needs to be escaped too.

Comment: `String replace1 = WEBSITE.replaceAll("\\{fromNumber\\}", String.valueOf(number));`. The curly braces in [RegEx](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) have a special purpose and therefore must be escaped. Also, you must replace with a string therefore convert **number** to string.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen C has already explained `replaceall` method's first argument is a [regex](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-regex).

Looks you are trying to replace `{fromNumber}` simple string with a given number. So instead of using `replaceall` use `replace` method which accepts a string as a first argument.

`String replace1 = WEBSITE.replace("{fromNumber}", number);`

Answer (score 0):

I is not working because '**{**' is a regex meta-character and replaceAll is using it as so. If you want to replace all "**{fromNumber}**" from you String then you have to :

> String replace1 = WEBSITE.replaceAll("\{fromNumber\}", number);

But if you just have to replace one then you can go with @lahiruk's answer and use

> String replace1 = WEBSITE.replace("{fromNumber}", number);

Something to add here , you can use replace any number of times if you know how many times your String will contain the String to be replaced.

---

### For more info

[Syntax of regexp.](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/regexp.5.asp)

[String.repaceAll()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall)